# addClass and removeClass not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to validate all teh required classes in a form and then display error message. In that addClass and removeClass is not working in IE8. Any help is appreciated on this.
Below is the code

```
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    //$(this).next('div.error_text').remove();//Not working in IE8
    //$(this).removeClass('required');//Not working in IE8
    $(this).after('<div class="error_text">Required</div>').remove();
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        //input.addClass('required');//Not working in IE8
        $(this).css("border","1px solid #FF0004");
        $(this).after('<div class="error_text">Required</div>');
        returnVal = false;
    }
    else{
        returnVal = true;
    }
});
```

Here if the field is not filled, it will create a red box around the field and display message. So if the user submits the form 2 or 3 times, that many times the message is displayed. So I want to remove that message first and then check if the field is empty and correspondingly add required. I tried to use addClass and removeClass and its not working. I am struggling with this since 1 day. Can some body please help me resolving this.....

Comment: What's the value of `input`?

Comment: I am not removing $(this). I m removing the div that is created after this . This div is created dynamically and used to display the error message

Comment: Hi Jack..I am not able to put in fiddle..I am getting some error in fiddle

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't work in IE 8...

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on IE8, you must give us more data on what you are trying to do.

Why are you trying to remove the class just to add it after? why not just remove it if the value is empty?
What is your jquery version?

I made a small test and worked just fine on IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .required {border:red solid 1px}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('div.error_text').remove();//Not working in IE8
if (!$this.val()) {
    $this.after('<div class="error_text">Required</div>');
    returnVal = false;
}
else{
    $this.removeClass('required');//Not working in IE8
     returnVal = true;
}
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <form id="submit_form">
    <input type="text" class="required" value="a">

    <br>
    <input type="text" class="required" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="required" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="required" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="required" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="required" value="">
    <br>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: say for eg, if the user submits the form first time without filling in details, the fields will become red and text"required "is displayed. So again if the user submits, the text gets added again.SO I am trying to remove it in the first..But that is not happening. Also if I try to add the class required using addClass its not taking that also.

Comment: That's not all of your code is it? You're missing a `DOCTYPE` and all of your closing tags `</body></html>`.

Comment: Now it has the `DOCTYPE` and all of your closing tags `</body></html>`.
I'll be more careful with copy past next type

Comment: @Paraíso No problem. Thanks for updating that. I removed my downvote. Good luck and happy coding! :)